# If $\mathscr{C}$ is the sheaf continuous real-valued functions on $X$, then when is $H^1(X,\mathscr{C})=0$?

Tags: sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

This is related to Hartshorne's Exercise III.2.7 here one shows that $H^1(S^1,\mathscr{R})=0$. Here, $\mathscr{R}$ is the sheaf of  germs of continuous real-valued functions. The method of proof is to look at the long exact sequence and show that we only need surjectivity of $\Gamma(X,\mathscr{F})\rightarrow\Gamma(X,\mathscr{F}/\mathscr{R})$ where $\mathscr{F}$ is the sheaf of *all* real-valued functions on $S^1$.

On examining the proof, only two properties seemed to be used. (1) $S^1$ is compact and (2) one can require that the finite cover $\{U_i\}$ satisfiy $U_i\cap U_j\cap U_k=\emptyset$.

My immediate thought is that we can claim (using the same proof) that $H^1(D^n,\mathscr{R})=0$ and $H^1(S^n,\mathscr{R})=0$ for $n\geq 1$. Can someone confirm if this is indeed the case (I think these sheaves should be soft)?

Comment: What is $\mathscr{R}$ ?

Comment: @Roland Sorry, it is the sheaf of continuous real-valued functions. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Yes $\mathscr{R}$ is soft on every paracompact space. Thus it has vanishing higher cohomology. Note however that you can't assume that $U_i\cap U_j\cap U_k=\emptyset$ on $S^n$ or $D^n$ for $n\geq 2$. It doesn't change the result though.

Comment: @Roland Thanks. If you'd like to submit what you said as an answer, I'll accept it as an answer.